# Django application with nginx and gunicorn only showing welcome page rest all pages showing 404 error

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2

I tried to deploy a sample django application in amazon ec2 server with the help of `nginx` and `gunicorn`. I added proxy pass in `nginx`. After I run the server and accessing my IP I was able to view the welcome to django page. But when I navigate to some other urls, say admin its shows 404 not found error.

How to fix this error.

**Nginx config:**

```
    upstream app {
            server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
            root /var/www/html;


            server_name IP;

            location /static/ {
                    root /home/ubuntu/workspace/business;
            }

            location / {

                    proxy_pass http://app;

                    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }
}
```

Comment: The information is not enough to track down the problem. Nginx config would be helpful here.

Comment: Assuming all your routes worked when running dev server locally? What does a sample route from your urls.py look like?

Comment: Try removing the `try_files` statement.

Comment: how is the 404 error like?, also try restarting the gunicorn service, if you use debian type sudo systemctl restart gunicorn, anyway check this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2):

You need change this:

```
location / {

         proxy_pass http://app;

         # First attempt to serve request as file, then
         # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

For this:

```
 location / {
      proxy_pass http://gunicorn:8888; #use your gunicorn port
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the line

`try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`

This line is causing every url except the main url to route to 404 page.
I removed it and hence working.

Thanks to [@Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith) for mentioning it in the comment